# Argument encoding: list of uints (uint[48])

Tags: web3js, python

Using python web3 module, attempting to call a contract function that takes one argument, a list of 48 uints:

`function checkOrderBatch(uint[48] input) external view returns(uint16[16] status, uint[16] amount) { ...`

Calling the function like so:

```
res = contract.functions.checkOrderBatch(o).call()
```

Where o is my input.

I've been able to successfully interact with this contract already with the python web3 module, but everything I try for this function returns an error about my input values.

Here are the things I've tried, and the errors I've recieved:

1. Input: List of 48, with each element being a string of the following form

   '0x0160e8043c35120bde2b0788f918bdd57160a127d2d56cea9c24a1342b45320c'

   Error:

> Could not identify the intended function with name `checkOrderBatch`, positional argument(s) of type `(<class 'list'>,)` and keyword argument(s) of type `{}`.
>   Found 1 function(s) with the name `checkOrderBatch`: ['checkOrderBatch(uint256[48])']
>   Function invocation failed due to improper argument encoding.

2. Input: List of 48, with each element being bytes of the following form

   b'0160e8043c35120bde2b0788f918bdd57160a127d2d56cea9c24a1342b45320c'

   Error: Same as #1
3. Input: List of 48, with each element being a string of the following form

   '0160e8043c35120bde2b0788f918bdd57160a127d2d56cea9c24a1342b45320c'

   Error: Same as #1
4. Input: List of 48, with each element being bytes of the follow form

   b'0x0160e8043c35120bde2b0788f918bdd57160a127d2d56cea9c24a1342b45320'

   Error: Same as #1
5. Input: 48 separate arguments.
   Error: As expected, incorrect number of arguments.

Clearly I'm not an expert in the data types intended here, so I'm likely doing something stupid. But I can't seem to figure it out. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

If you would like something to test, here is the specific contract:

https://etherscan.io/address/0x37304b0ab297f13f5520c523102797121182fb5b#code

The function is checkOrderBatch. It is a view function, so you can mess with it without wasting gas. If you can submit anything to it and get past the point I got, that's all I need! It's ok if the function returns an error. I just need to get the encoding right.

Thank you!

Comment: I would think it should be a list of numbers: `[0, 1, 2,  ...]`

Comment: Thx smarx. So are you saying i should do hex to decimal conversion on those strings? I know the content that needs to go in, just not the proper encoding

Answer (score 2):

I knew I was doing something stupid due to being relatively new to this ...

For anyone who's curious, this is what I was missing:

```
int(your_string_here,16)
```